# Olive to convert Whisper Model to Onnx

Tags: python, c#, onnx, olive

I am trying to convert OpenAi Whisper model to Onnx with Olive, to merge the Model Files into one file, using:

```
python prepare_whisper_configs.py --model_name openai/whisper-tiny.en
python -m olive.workflows.run --config whisper_cpu_fp32.json --setup
python -m olive.workflows.run --config whisper_cpu_fp32.json
```

Github: https://github.com/microsoft/Olive

Olive Documentation: https://microsoft.github.io/Olive/overview/quicktour.html

I am getting error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\OliveEnv\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in
> _run_module_as_main
> return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\OliveEnv\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in
> *run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\OliveEnv\lib\site-packages\olive\workflows\run_*main**.py",
> line 17, in 
> run(**vars(args))   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\OliveEnv\lib\site-packages\olive\workflows\run\run.py",
> line 187, in run
> return engine.run(   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\OliveEnv\lib\site-packages\olive\engine\engine.py",
> line 347, in run
> run_result = self.run_accelerator(   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\OliveEnv\lib\site-packages\olive\engine\engine.py",
> line 412, in run_accelerator
> return self.run_no_search(   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\OliveEnv\lib\site-packages\olive\engine\engine.py",
> line 483, in run_no_search
> should_prune, signal, model_ids = self._run_passes(   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\OliveEnv\lib\site-packages\olive\engine\engine.py",
> line 887, in _run_passes
> model_config, model_id = self._run_pass(   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\OliveEnv\lib\site-packages\olive\engine\engine.py",
> line 985, in _run_pass
> output_model_config = host.run_pass(p, input_model_config, data_root, output_model_path, pass_search_point)   File
> "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\OliveEnv\lib\site-packages\olive\systems\local.py",
> line 32, in run_pass
> output_model = the_pass.run(model, data_root, output_model_path, point)   File
> "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\OliveEnv\lib\site-packages\olive\passes\olive_pass.py",
> line 367, in run
> output_model = self._run_for_config(model, data_root, config, output_model_path)   File
> "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\OliveEnv\lib\site-packages\olive\passes\onnx\conversion.py",
> line 58, in _run_for_config
> return self._convert_model_on_device(model, data_root, config, output_model_path, "cpu")   File
> "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\OliveEnv\lib\site-packages\olive\passes\onnx\conversion.py",
> line 73, in *convert_model_on_device
> component_model = model.get_component(component_name)   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\OliveEnv\lib\site-packages\olive\model_*init**.py",
> line 696, in get_component
> user_module_loader = UserModuleLoader(self.model_script, self.script_dir)   File
> "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\OliveEnv\lib\site-packages\olive\common\user_module_loader.py",
> line 22, in **init**
> self.user_module = import_user_module(user_script, script_dir)   File
> "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\OliveEnv\lib\site-packages\olive\common\import_lib.py",
> line 39, in import_user_module
> return import_module_from_file(user_script)   File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\OliveEnv\lib\site-packages\olive\common\import_lib.py",
> line 27, in import_module_from_file
> spec.loader.exec_module(new_module)   File "", line 883, in exec_module   File
> "", line 241, in
> *call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\OpenAI\Olive\examples\whisper\code\user_script.py", line 10, in
>
> from olive.model import PyTorchModelHandler ImportError: cannot import name 'PyTorchModelHandler' from 'olive.model'
> (C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\OliveEnv\lib\site-packages\olive\model_*init**.py)

I have a Conda environment: OliveEnv

Packages installed:

```
(OliveEnv) C:\OpenAI\Olive\examples\whisper>pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- ----------
alembic                1.13.1
certifi                2024.2.2
charset-normalizer     3.3.2
colorama               0.4.6
coloredlogs            15.0.1
colorlog               6.8.2
contextlib2            21.6.0
contourpy              1.2.0
cycler                 0.12.1
Deprecated             1.2.14
filelock               3.13.1
flatbuffers            23.5.26
fonttools              4.48.1
fsspec                 2024.2.0
greenlet               3.0.3
huggingface-hub        0.20.3
humanfriendly          10.0
idna                   3.6
Jinja2                 3.1.3
joblib                 1.3.2
kiwisolver             1.4.5
Mako                   1.3.2
MarkupSafe             2.1.5
matplotlib             3.8.2
mpmath                 1.3.0
networkx               3.2.1
neural-compressor      2.4.1
numpy                  1.26.4
olive-ai               0.3.2
onnx                   1.15.0
onnxruntime            1.17.0
opencv-python-headless 4.9.0.80
optuna                 3.5.0
packaging              23.2
pandas                 2.2.0
pillow                 10.2.0
pip                    23.3.1
prettytable            3.9.0
protobuf               3.20.3
psutil                 5.9.8
py-cpuinfo             9.0.0
pycocotools            2.0.7
pydantic               1.10.14
pyparsing              3.1.1
pyreadline3            3.4.1
python-dateutil        2.8.2
pytz                   2024.1
PyYAML                 6.0.1
regex                  2023.12.25
requests               2.31.0
safetensors            0.4.2
schema                 0.7.5
scikit-learn           1.4.0
scipy                  1.12.0
setuptools             68.2.2
six                    1.16.0
SQLAlchemy             2.0.25
sympy                  1.12
tabulate               0.9.0
threadpoolctl          3.2.0
tokenizers             0.15.1
torch                  2.2.0
torchmetrics           0.10.3
tqdm                   4.66.1
transformers           4.37.2
typing_extensions      4.9.0
tzdata                 2023.4
urllib3                2.2.0
wcwidth                0.2.13
wheel                  0.41.2
wrapt                  1.16.0
```

I have tried three different versions of olive, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.4.0

A very good video, showing the use of Olive is MS Build:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_0N1VL5ZmA
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qj-l0tGKPf8

Answer (score 0):

I installed from git:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/microsoft/Olive#egg=olive-ai[cpu]
```

See: https://microsoft.github.io/Olive/0.2.1/getstarted/installation.html

Installing git: https://git-scm.com/download/win

See: https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/pip-install-git/

No explanation, its now working. Odd!